# "No runtime available" in MobileFirst console in AIX

Tags: aix, ibm-mobilefirst

**Application Server**

- AIX V7.1
- WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.4
- Java SDK V7.0.8
- MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3
- DB2 V10.1 client

**Database Server**

- AIX V7.1
- DB2 V10.1

Application Center database has been created and the APPSCHM schema has been created with it's tables.

MobileFirst database has been created with WRKLGHT, WLADMIN, & WLREPORT

WAS is setup with federated security using LDAP and internal repository.  Using internal id of WASADMIN for WAS console, epicenter console, and MobileFirst console.

Application center WAR installed and the console is accessible. I can login to it using WASADMIN.

MobileFirst console is accessible and I can login to it using WASADMIN.

XML file configured for ANT deployment of project runtime environment. I supplied WAR file built in MobileFirst Studio. Everything was appropriately configured.  Using DB2 instance owner userid/password to ensure there are no permission issues.  Using WASADMIN for ANT to do deployment to WAS.

Did the following ANT commands:

```
ant -f myproject.xml databases
ant -f myproject.xml install
```

Project runtime environment is deployed with no errors reported in ANT log.

WAS is restarted.

I then go to the MobileFirst console in the browser (Firefox) and the console says there are no runtime environments.

There are no errors in the WAS logs.

I used the same project WAR on Windows V8.1 wit WAS V8.5.5.4 running on Windows, but used the Server Configuration Tool (not available on AIX). and my runtime environment shows up in the MobileFirst console.

Why is my project runtime environment not showing in the MobileFirst console when I deploy on AIX using ANT for deployment?

BTW - My MobileFirst application runs in MobileFirst Studio using WAS Liberty profile and I can connect to it using my mobile devices.

I can also deploy to full WAS in a Windows environment using the Server Configuration Tool and then deploy my *.wlapp and adapters and then connect to it using my mobile devices.

We have had the same app running on RedHat Linux.

This only seems to fail on AIX.

[ZIP Archive of log files on Google Drive (no signin required)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1bvkvfcnVs7OUFfTUVMV2tvS0k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide all logs from server anyway. Zip them and upload to Dropbox or any other service.

Comment: From the logs, the communication between the runtime and the admin seems to happen well - [6/15/15 22:10:38:278 EDT] 00000092 ManagementMXB I   Result: LiquidMobile: server1/lexbz2185Node01Cell/lexbz2185Node01/9.51.102.185: Runtime was synchronized successfully
  This is strange that the runtime is not displayed in the console. Did you try a few minutes after the server starts to make sure everything is synchronized when you access the console ?

Comment: @james, Can you reply to Didier's question? "Did you try a few minutes after the server starts to make sure everything is synchronized when you access the console?"

Comment: Also: do you have a version of firefox sufficently recent ? (29 or later). Do you have errors in the web console (Net tab) ?

Comment: @Didier, Yes, I waited for everything to synchronize before I accessed the console.  And I have Firefox 38.

Comment: I have resolved this particular issue.  I completely uninstalled MobileFirst from our AIX server.  I reinstalled MobileFirst using Installation manager and applied the iFix dated 6/8/2015.  During the reinstallation I did not allow Installation Manager to create the Application Center.  I then recreated the databases manually for the Application Center and for the Worklight Console.  I manually installed the Application Center EAR and configured WAS manually.  I manually installed the Worklight Console WAR and configured WAS manually.

Comment: I reinstalled our MobileFirst project runtime environment using ANT.  I restarted WAS and now my runtime environment shows up in the Worklight console.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this particular issue myself.

I cannot say for sure which of these things resolved the issue, but nevertheless, the issue was resolved.

I completely uninstalled MobileFirst from our AIX server using IBM Installation Manager (IM).  I manually removed any remaining directories and files from the file system that MobileFirst had created.  I cleaned up WebSphere Application Server (WAS) via the WAS Console by making sure that all WARs, datasources, JDBC providers, etc., were removed.

I then reinstalled MobileFirst using IM and applied the iFix dated 6/8/2015. During the reinstallation I did not allow Installation Manager to create the Application Center.

After the IM installation portion, I then recreated the databases manually for the Application Center and for Worklight. The Worklight has the three schema for worklight, admin, and reporting, and I manually installed the Application Center EAR and configured WAS manually to setup JDBC provider, datasource, and LDAP security.

I manually installed the Worklight Console WAR and configured WAS manually to setup JDBC provider, datasource, and LDAP security.

I reinstalled our MobileFirst project runtime environment using ANT. I restarted WAS and now my runtime environment shows up in the Worklight console.